# Extract roads from a google earth image

Tags: java, google-maps, open-source, image-processing

i am wondering if there is any opensource and freeware solution to extract roads from an image, like google map images?
i think it maybe possible to code something like that with AI solutions, but i dont know where to start 
thnx

Comment: For what purpose?  What do you mean by extract?

Answer (score 3):

If you're mainly interested in the results, instead of an algorithm, you may want to check out [OpenStreetMaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

Otherwise, you should focus on computer vision solutions and a framework such as OpenCV in order to process raw imagery and filter out streets based on their features – which is not trivial.

Comment: thnx for reply, openSteetMaps is not suitable for me, because i am working on village roads and mountain roads, and OSM doesnt support that.(at least in my country).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it would be a valuable resource to cartographers ranging from 'street directory' publishers to the military.

I'm sure proprietary commercial software exists, but open source and freeware — probably not.